# How to properly set up a ToMany relation with Objectbox in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, one-to-many, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

The Objectbox is setup fine. It works for other entities.
This is the class I want to store in the Objectbox:

```
class A {

 String id;
 List<B> fieldA;
 List<B> fieldB;

}
```

The custom class B instances stored in fieldA and fieldB are all unique and won't be stored in the other field again.

My entity classes look like this:

```
@Entity
class AEntity{
  
  @Id(assignable: true)
  int dbId = 0;
  
  String id;
  final classBRelation1 = ToMany<CustomClassBEntity>();
  final classBRelation2 = ToMany<CustomClassBEntity>();

}

@Entity
class BEntity {
 
 @Id(assignable: true)
 int dbId = 0;

 String id;
 String field;
}
```

I keep getting this error: "the dbIdProperty is null"
I also tried making the id not assignable and not assigning the "0" but nothing worked.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at https://docs.objectbox.io/relations